# Google sheets weighted average function: How do I set this to only use non-zero values?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, weighted-average

I'm new to Google sheets / excel and I'm a bit lost.
Column E is found by D/C. How do I find the weighted average (B6), but only for values in the E column that have not been filled in yet?

I tried <>"" but it showed an error.

[image: screenshot of relevant portion of google sheet]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve that, here is a simple one

```
=AVERAGE.WEIGHTED(filter(E2:E5,D2:D5<>""),filter(B2:B5,D2:D5<>""))
```

Comment: FYI. I need to switch comma (,) into semicolon (;)